# Installing Python 2.7.11 without sudo and make

Tags: python, linux

I'm doing a little project and I need to install a different version of python on a box on which I don't have superuser rights. Already tried installing python to a directory for which I do have permissions, but I would still need to build it using make, which the box doesn't have installed. Any ideas?

Comment: You could download the source and work from there.

Comment: Do you have access to `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: @Uzzee Yes, but I would still need the make command to build from source, which I don't have access too

Comment: @Makoto I managed to get pip to work by installing it to my $home dir and using the --user argument when installing modules, would I be able to change my python version with pip? Or install a compatibility module?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want to use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to install python

Comment: I would, if I had sudo or make.

Comment: Well, sounds like you need a better box then. https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/ - should be good enough for $5/month

Comment: unfortunately I'm stuck with my current provider for another year

Answer (score 1):

Since you can run `pip`, you can install a virtual environment to play in.  For that, I recommend [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is installable via `pip install virtualenvwrapper`.

The docs on the linked site have more details on what you need to do to get it up and running.

Comment: Good idea, got virtualenv setup now,but how do I get the 2.7.11 executable to work if I cant compile the source because I don't have make?